# class ClassName( variables)(spark: SparkSession) {}

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have seen declaring classes like below in scala-spark projects

```
class ClassName( var1: String,var2: String)(spark: SparkSession) {

}
```

I would like to understand what is the use case of `(spark: SparkSession)` in the class. How does it help. what is it called? I searched in the internet , but couldn't find a proper answer for this. Could somebody help me to understand this concept. Appreciate any small help in this.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a *parameter list*. `spark` is called a *parameter*.

A *parameter* is like a "hole" in the definition of a subroutine (in this case, the constructor). When you invoke the subroutine (in this case invoke the constructor via the `new` operator), you can pass an *argument* for each parameter, which is used to fill the "hole" in the subroutine definition.

Comment: Is there any practical application for this argument list feature when it comes to class constructors? One [documented](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html) use case of argument lists/currying seems to be partial application, but it didn't work when I tried it on class constructor argument list... Sorry, also learning Scala.

Comment: @ernest_k Maybe that `SparkSession` was supposed to be an implicit parameter? To enable that, a separate parameter list makes sense (and is necessary).